# List from string of digits

Tags: python

I'm getting a string from input() which consists of digits separated by spaces (1 5 6 3). First I'm trying to check that the input only consists of digits with the isdigit() function but because of the spaces I can't get it to work. Then I convert the string to a list using the split() function.

What I need is to make a list from input and make sure it only consists of digits, else send a message and ask for a new input. Is it maybe possible to add a parameter to isdigit() that makes an exception for spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing is a *look before you leap* approach, i.e. checking first whether the input is conforming, and then parsing it. It's more pythonic to use a *Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission* approach, i.e. just do it and handle exceptions:

```
s = raw_input() # input() in Python 3
try:
  numbers = map(int, s.split())
except ValueError:
  print('Invalid format')
```

Comment: Upon trying this code the "Invalid format" print does not show even when i input letters.

Comment: @Sergei You may have somehow suppressed prints. `int('a')` will always throw a `ValueError`.

Comment: I dont really understand how map() works... this makes it hard for me to find why it's not working

Comment: @Sergei: the equivalent of this `map` function would be: `[int(i) for i in s.split()]`

Comment: @Sergei No, problem, `map` is [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map). It applies its first argument to every element in the second one. Here, the second argument is a list generated by `split()`. For example, for an input `1 2a 3`, the list looks like `['1', '2a', '3']`. Now, `map` creates the list `[int('1'), int('2a'), int('3')]`. The call `int('2a')` raises the `ValueError`. If we'd have inputted the stirng `1 2 3`, the result would be `[1, 2, 3]`. Instead of `map`, you can also use a `for` loop or a list comprehension (see @eumiro's comment for that).

Answer (score 0):

Probably a lot more complicated than it needs to be but this will return true if the string consists of only digits:

```
not sum([not i.isdigit() for i in thestring.split()])
```

Comment: or a little bit simpler and faster: `all(i.isdigit() for i in thestring.split())`

Comment: or `thestring.replace(' ','').isdigit()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should try converting and, upon exception ask again. This is how I'd do it. (I've included a Ctrl+c escape to avoid being locked in the loop.

```
import sys

list = None
while True:
    try:
        print "Enter your digits : ",
        content = raw_input()
        list = [int(x) for x in content.strip().split(" ")]
        break
     except KeyboardInterrupt: # Presses Ctrl+C
        print "Exiting due to keyboard interrupt"
        sys.exit(-1)
     except:
        print "Bad content, only digits separated by spaces"
print list
```